# Name for siblings born on the same date but several years apart?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Me and my sister were both born on December 5th, but she was born in 1990 and I was born in 1999. Is there a term/name for this occurrence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [People of different ages who share the same birthday](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270798/people-of-different-ages-who-share-the-same-birthday)

Comment: *Family planning*?

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that there is a term used for this occurrence, even if there is I am not aware of it.

However you could use:

shared birthday

joint birthday

split birthday

Comment: "Half birthday" means something else.

Comment: Oh I am really sorry I will change it right away.

Answer (score -2):

The term for this is *Irish twins*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This term generally means "children born to the same parents within one year of each other" (eg [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Irish%20twins) is pretty unanimous on this). The term seems to be common in the US, but not so much in the UK where it is likely to be taken as somewhat racist.

Comment: You have to put a dot at the end of a written sentence.

Comment: I'm afraid this is given at the duplicate question (yes, it is a duplicate and I'm just about to deal with that) and has a -8 score because it doesn't mean sharing a birthday.